# Filter parent data source with a field which is in another table in D365

Tags: sql, axapta, outer-join, dynamics-365-operations

Some times we need to filter a form grid based on the status of the transaction reference Id. Assume that we want to show purchase orders with confirm document state in arrival overview form. The document state field is located in the purch table. For this aim, I try to outer join WMSArrivalOverviewTmp to purch table and add Range. However the results is not as I expect.
This is the code I have tried in the initialized data source event:

```
 [FormDataSourceEventHandler(formDataSourceStr(WMSArrivalOverview, WMSArrivalOverviewTmp), FormDataSourceEventType::Initialized)]
    public static void WMSArrivalOverviewTmp_OnInitialized(FormDataSource sender, FormDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        QueryBuildDataSource    qbds    = sender.queryBuildDataSource();
        QueryBuildDataSource    qbdsPO;

        qbdsPO  = qbds.addDataSource(tableNum(PurchTable));

        qbdsPO.clearRange(fieldNum(PurchTable, DocumentState));

        qbdsPO.joinMode(JoinMode::OuterJoin);
        qbdsPO.fetchMode(QueryFetchMode::One2One);
        qbdsPO.addLink(fieldNum(WMSArrivalOverviewTmp, InventTransRefId ),fieldNum(PurchTable, PurchId), qbds.name());
        qbdsPO.relations(false);
        qbdsPO.addRange(fieldNum(PurchTable, DocumentState)).value(SysQuery::value(VersioningDocumentState::Confirmed));
        info(sender.query().toString());
    }
```

This is the query which has been shown :

> SELECT FIRSTFAST * FROM WMSArrivalOverviewTmp(WMSArrivalOverviewTmp)
>   OUTER JOIN FROM PurchTable(PurchTable_1) ON
>   WMSArrivalOverviewTmp.InventTransRefId = PurchTable.PurchId AND
>   ((DocumentState = 40))

Also, I have changed the event type to query executing but I get errors:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting
>   data type nvarchar to bigint.
>   Cannot select a record in Purchase orders (PurchTable). The SQL
>   database has issued an error.

P.S. I have noticed that the error comes when I click on the update button after I fill one of the field in the filter section(arrival option). For example when I fill account number or warehouse. And also I have noticed that when I click on the update button while the fields are not filled in the filter section the join operation has not applied correctly, i.e., the purchase orders which have draft status are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual query looks correct to me. I would add that you may want to add the link between the `WMSArrivalOverviewTmp.InventTransType == InventTransType::Purch` (or set `qbds.relations(true)` so that you use the table's built in relation), but I doubt that is the root of your problem. Of course it wouldn't hurt to make sure your query works in the manner that you expect it to by converting the results of the info() call you have into SQL code and run it in SSMS to double check the result set.

Also, I'm curious why would you put the event on the datasource you are trying to manipulate? I would recommend investigating to see if it can occur on the `OnModified` event of the "status of the transaction reference Id". Although perhaps I am misunderstanding - if this situation is more of a "*we need to happen all the time when the form loads*" than a "*some times we need*" as you start your question off - the place to change the query is to modify it in a handler of the datasource's `OnQueryExecuting` event.

There are two ways of modifying the query on an event when an event occurs.

```
FormRun formRun = sender.formRun() as FormRun;
FormDataSource formDataSource = formRun.dataSource(formDataSourceStr(WMSArrivalOverview, WMSArrivalOverviewTmp));

//First way - get the base query and use executeQuery() to reload changes
Query query = formDataSource.query();
//modified query here.
formDataSource.executeQuery();


//Second way - get the current queryRun query and use research() to reload changes
Query query = formDataSource.queryRun.query();
//modified query here.
formDataSource.research();
```

Comment: Dear @rjv, "sometimes" I mean for some forms, and the corrected sentence is we need to happen all the time for some forms when they loads. I get those errors if I use outer join, other join types are OK. but you know I need to use outer join. because the status field is not in the form data source.

Comment: What's the result of the x++ query when you print it out using the info method you have at the bottom of your code?

Comment: Dear rjv I have updated my question. Now you can see the query value in my question. Thank you for your support.

Comment: The error you have seems to be that you are trying to pass a string into an int column, but your query appears to have correctly formatted documentstate to 40 which is an int. Your postscript is confusing me though, I'm not sure the layout of your form or the code that is executing when you click the update button. I'm not sure if you have multiple errors or just one at this point. I would start with determining how to remove the data type error and see what happens after that point.